# Unknown Error in koa.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise, koa

I'm working on a node.js project in my linux based wordpress. Just today I needed to run it in OSX.

Everything installed perfectly. But while tried to run the application got this kind of error which has no reason. Is there anyone who faced same kind of issue, if yes, what is the solutuon?

```
TypeError: #<Promise> is not a function
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Object.exports.indexAction (/Users/nixon/Documents/node/madefreshly-3/application/controllers/dashboardController.js:26:24)
  at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.next (native)
  at Object.dispatch (/Users/nixon/Documents/node/madefreshly-3/node_modules/koa-router/lib/router.js:96:44)
  at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.next (native)
  at Object.next (/Users/nixon/Documents/node/madefreshly-3/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:74:21)
  at /Users/nixon/Documents/node/madefreshly-3/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:93:18
  at /Users/nixon/Documents/node/madefreshly-3/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:224:7
  at in_the_handler (/Users/nixon/Documents/node/madefreshly-3/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:237:18)
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:372:11)
```

Line of code from dashboard.js

```
24      var raw7DayTotalSale = yield ships.ship.find({"ship_shipped": {'$gt' : last7Day}, store_id: this.session.loggedId}).where('ship_paid').ne('0').exec();
25      var last7dayTotalSale = 0;
26      raw7DayTotalSale.forEach(co(function* (item) {
27           last7dayTotalSale += Number(item.ship_total);
28        }));
```

Comment: Could you show dashboardController.js:26 this code ?

Comment: what node version do you use ?

Comment: do you run node with --harmony option ?

Comment: yes. Everything works. Login, simple authentications etc. Just whenever any method has **Array.forEach**. It stops working and showing errors like this.

Comment: Why are you using `co(function *` in the `forEach` it's a synchronous action... Instead fo `.forEach(function(item){` and you'll be good to go

Comment: But why it's working on my Linux Workspace?

Comment: Probably different versions of Node (for mac and linux) - while stuff like Node (or Java, or Python etc) is all cross platform there might be different compile options in place. You can _probably_ get it working by compiling node yourself.

Comment: WTH do you use koa at all for a simple `reduce` operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of co returns a **promise** rather than a **function**.

So `.forEach()` is trying to call the **Promise** as if it were a **function**.

I imagine you have a different version of co on each machine

> co@4.0.0 has been released, which relies promises. It is now a
>   stepping stone towards ES7 async/await. The primary API change is how
>   co() is invoked. Before, co returned a "thunk", which you then call
>   with a callback with optional arguments. Now, co() returns a promise.

https://github.com/tj/co#co-v4